# Areas and iterations, permissions required

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

What are the correct permissions/settings to allow an user to create/edit areas and iterations?

I have an user that is getting this message in the admin section of  areas or iterations:

```
You do not have one or more permissions required to update the iterations for this team
```

The weird thing is that the user can indeed create/edit areas and iterations, this user is part of a TFS Group I created for the Project, the Security properties of this group are:

```
Create test runs - Allow 
Delete team project - Not Set 
Delete test runs - Allow 
Edit project-level information - Not Set 
Manage test configurations - Allow 
Manage test environments - Allow 
View project-level information - Allow 
View test runs - Allow
```

The Security of Areas and Iterations have allow to everything.

This used to be enough in TFS 2010, but it don't know why the message appears in TFS 2012.

Another thing, If I change the Security Property of  "Edit project-level information" to Allow the user does not get the message, but in TFS 2010 this setting allowed users to change the permissions of another users and I don't want that.

Comment: There are also security settings on the Area and Iteration nodes themselves. The above configuration should give you the appropriate permissions without having to go down to the area/iteration level of security, though. Just something you may want to check.

Comment: I have "inherited allow" in the nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if its the correct answer, but i added my custom group to the Project "Team". I have to read more about this Teams thing in TFS2012.

Answer (score 2):

U can use TFS Sidekick to effectively see how a users inherited different permissions on the different area's in TFS. U can use this tool to check out other projects where the permissions work and see if the adjustments u made had the effect u wanted. I dont advice to change permissions by this tool but use the administrator console to give this permissions to the group u want to.

[Tfs 2012 Sidekick](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/)

Comment: Not much help, I have the same project and areas permissions but I still get the warning message, the only way to avoid it is to add my custom TFS group as member of the default project team.

Answer (score 0):

You (as project admin) have to use security policies on Iteration and area nodes from project web portal. (ex: `http://tfsxxxx:8080/tfs/<collection>/<project>/_admin/_iterations  ..../_areas`).

Select an iteration or area node, right-click and select Security in order to set right to:

- Create child nodes
- Delete this node
- Edit this node
- View permissions for this node